# Mina SFTP : Has anyone attempted to use MINA as a SFTP server against Hadoop or a custom file system?

Tags: filesystems, hdfs, sftp, apache-mina

Am trying to use Apache MINA as a SFTP server to a custom file system that is very similar to HDFS. Has anyone attempted anything like this before ?

Reading a directory, reading a file and writing to a file should be delegated to my custom methods.

Answer (score 0):

This has been definitely attempted before and some SFTP servers even define a custom file system API that make this easier. This seems to apply to Apache MINA SSHd as well.

I have done something similar in my SFTP/WS server for Node.js - one only needs to implement 18 methods to get full SFTP v3 support. These custom methods (see the [`IFilesystem` interface](https://github.com/lukaaash/sftp-ws/blob/master/src/lib/sftp-api.ts) as an example) correspond to [SFTP protocol requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-secsh-filexfer-03#page-6) (packet types 3 to 20), which *slightly* resembles the POSIX API (there are some odd differences to look out for, however).

Although I don't have any experience with Apache MINA SSHd, it looks like this is possible as well. It provides an [`SshFile` interface](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=mina-sshd.git;a=tree;f=sshd-core/src/main/java/org/apache/sshd/server;hb=9e97a8249b900bf927748fa8b0be2474d89477d2) (it represents both a file and a directory, despite its name), which is used by MINA's SFTP subsystem, and provides "native" implementations that are used by default. In addition to this interface, there is `FileSystemView` interface (whose purpose is to resolve paths into instances of `SshFile`) and `FileSystemFactory`. I guess the authors actually had your scenario in mind - once you provide a custom implementation if MINA's `SshFile` (and related interfaces) that uses your custom file system instead of the "native" one, you are almost done.